# Fill NaN in pandas dataframe with interpolate function

Tags: pandas, python-3.7, missing-data

I find a row contains two missing data from my dataframe.

```
data
WeatherHR0     6.4
WeatherHR1       6
WeatherHR2     5.8
WeatherHR3     5.4
WeatherHR4     NaN
WeatherHR5     NaN
WeatherHR6     4.7
WeatherHR7     4.7
WeatherHR8     4.7
WeatherHR9     3.8
WeatherHR10      3
WeatherHR11      3
WeatherHR12    2.6
WeatherHR13    2.2
WeatherHR14    2.2
WeatherHR15    2.4
WeatherHR16    2.5
WeatherHR17    2.4
WeatherHR18    2.3
WeatherHR19    2.4
WeatherHR20    2.6
WeatherHR21    2.3
WeatherHR22      2
WeatherHR23    1.8
Name: 2008-04-12 00:00:00, dtype: object
```

[image]

I tried to interpolate the missing values with pandas' interpolate() function. But it didn't work. I couldn't figure out why. Can someone explain the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that the interpolate() can't handle dtype: object.

I changed

`data = df.loc['2008-04-12',"WeatherHR0":"WeatherHR23"]` to

`data = df.loc['2008-04-12',"WeatherHR0":"WeatherHR23"].astype(float)`

Then it could fill the missing data.

[image]